# Can you do everything with grep that you can do with egrep?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

If I use a lot of backslashes, can I do any regular expression with grep?  So far, it seems so.

I mean, without grep -E also. So just "grep regex file", with many backslashes where needed.

Comment: `can I do any regular expression with grep?` yes, is that all?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
man egrep
```

"In addition, two variant programs egrep and fgrep are available.  **egrep is the same as grep -E**.  fgrep is the same as grep -F.  Direct invocation  as  either  egrep  or
       fgrep is deprecated, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified."

-E means extended regular expressions, still man egrep:
"grep understands three different versions of regular expression syntax: “basic,” “extended” and “perl.” In GNU grep, there is no difference in  available  functionality
       between  basic  and  extended  syntaxes.   In other implementations, basic regular expressions are less powerful.  The following description applies to extended regular
       expressions; differences for basic regular expressions are summarized afterwards.  Perl regular  expressions  give  additional  functionality,  and  are  documented  in
       pcresyntax(3) and pcrepattern(3), but may not be available on every system."

Comment: I mean, without grep -E also.  So just grep <regex> <file>, with many backslashes where needed.

Comment: @user3465829 You should probably clarify that in your question. A lot of people (myself included) are coming to this question assuming you don't know that `grep -E` and `egrep` are interchangeable.